# using office-ui-fabric within dotnet core &&react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, .net-core, webpack-style-loader

I have a dotnet core && react application , in which I'd like to use Office-ui-fabric library .

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app_fabric_test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.37.1"
  }
}
```

It works until I start to use the lib, I tried to import

```
import { DefaultButton, PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
```

So I get this result :

[image: app]

It seems that the page works fine in background, but it is hidden by the error message popup.

So How can I fix this problem ? otherwise how can I avoid this type of errors to be shown ?

thanks,

Answer (score -1):

This problem has been fixed in new template using update asp.net core 2.1 and visual studio 15.7